# $("#win").data("kendoWindow") is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, kendo-ui

I am working on a ReactJS project combined with JQuery and Kendo UI.
Inside `HTML` body there is a `<div id="win">` .

In a script, on a user click event I create a `kendo` window using

> $("#win").kendoWindow({...})

This part works perfectly fine, and `kendo` popup window appears, but I have a problem getting a reference to this `kendo` window using this command:

> var w = $("#win").data("kendoWindow");

but w is always undefined.

If I take a look at `$("win")` object via Chrome console, I can see two jQuery related properties that I think could be the problem.

> jQuery33106159918714740461: {events: {...}, handle: f}
>   jQuery33106159918714740462: {handler: init, kendoWindow: init}

I believe that there should be only one of them, and that is causing the problem, but I don't know how this properties are created.

Do someone understand what is actually going on and what could be the problem ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding

> import $ from 'jquery';

to JSX file.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code.

var w = $("#win");

w.kendoWindow({ width: "500px",title: "About Josef Hoffmann" });

w.data("kendoWindow") here you can get the object.

Comment: Tried it ... still getting undefined.

Comment: can you share the screen shot? Or may be you missing destroy() when close kendo window.

Comment: Nope, this problem occurs before closing the window so I don't believe destroy() is causing the problem. I create a window inside javascript function and immediately try to access it to center it and open, but can't get reference to it.

Comment: Try from this link.    https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/window/how-to/make-popup-appear-in-center        it works with me.

Comment: I think that it has to do something with other components in project. This works fine when used in pure JQuery project, but here we are using react and perhaps it causes Kendo to act somewhat differently...

Comment: sorry then may be I can't help you.